# Mongoose query to list all the groups that a user joined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const groupSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: "", required: true },
  participants: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
  }],
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, default: "", required: true },
  name: { type: String, default: "", required: true },
});
```

I'm trying to fetch all the groups the given user is joined. This is my try

```
userModel.findOne({ username: data.username }, function(err, user) {
  if (user) {
      groupModel
      .find({"participants":{"$in":[user]}
      .populate('participants')         
      .exec(function(err, result) {
       .....
       }
  }
 });
```

I'm getting an empty list in for the above query
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like you just need to do:

```
groupModel.find({participants: user._id}).exec(...
```

Comment: What's the result of above query?

Comment: Im getting an empty list

Comment: one example is  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc655efc4b4433d8c3e2468"), 
    "name" : "Conversation", 
    "participants" : [
        "5dc2822a2d9d9a3ae51a3def", 
        "5dc2825c2d9d9a3ae51a3df0"
    ],  
    "admins" : [

    ], 
}

Comment: I got the issue  It was with with saving the  object.. Sorry.. thank you for your time